# How to save the number of elements in a list as a variable in c#?

Tags: c#, list, variables

I am looking to make it so that the computer tests to find the number of elements in a list, and then saves that as a variable.

```
        int incmount = 0;
        List<int> items = new List<int>();
        int numofit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < numofit; i++)
        {

            items.Add(incmount);
            incmount++;

        }
```

in the example above, I would like to find the number of element in the list "items" and save it as a variable.

Comment: You have already that number. It is _numofit_. Could you explain what do you mean with _the number of element in the list "items"_

Comment: the list is called items, on the second line. I want to find the number of elements in that list.. If I were to change the number again later on, then numofit would no longer be valid for this purpose?

Comment: All right, but your code doesn't explain your problem. However I suggest you that you should search the MSDN on these basic properties of classes. For example you could find everything about generic lists at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of elements in the list *items* can be access via:

```
items.Count
```

Like this:

```
    int incmount = 0;
    List<int> items = new List<int>();
    int numofit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < numofit; i++)
    {

        items.Add(incmount);
        incmount++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Number of items: {0}", items.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
items.Count;
```

but if u need more fun

```
int count = list.Count(i => i > 10);// get the count of those which is bigger than 10
```